# vertical line glitch/bug issue in css while using filter property

Tags: css, filter

There's some awkward vertical line glitch apparently due to filter property(applied on image's hover state) while hovering on a image in chrome(It works fine in mozilla firefox). I have searched on the web but all I could find are kind of similar glitches/bugs or whatever while using backdrop-filter property. So a specific explanation or workaround to these glitch/bug/rendering problem due to this filter property in css would be really nice.
Here's my html code:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.7;
    padding: 3rem;
    color: #777;
}

.header-tertiary {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.row {
    max-width: 114rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.story {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 3rem 6rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 6rem;
    padding-left: 9rem;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    transform: skewX(-12deg);
}

.story__shape {
    width: 15rem;
    height: 15rem;
    float: left;
    shape-outside: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    transform: translateX(-3rem) skewX(12deg);
    position: relative;
}

.story__img {
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-3rem) scale(1.4);
    transition: all .5s;
}

.story-text {
    transform: skewX(12deg);
}

.story__caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 30%);
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.story:hover .story__caption {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.story:hover .story__img {
    filter: blur(2px) brightness(80%);
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px) brightness(80%);
    transform: translateX(-3rem) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="story">
            <figure class="story__shape">
                <img class="story__img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612306055306-e72bd105ad3d?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1225&q=80" alt="story image">
                <figcaption class="story__caption">
                    Mary Smith
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <div class="story-text">
                <h3 class="header-tertiary u-margin-bottom-small">
                    I had the best week ever with my family
                </h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem doloribus voluptatem nisi vel hic suscipit repellendus eum, sed earum placeat quaerat, laboriosam dolores atque ratione odio quidem reprehenderit ea ab. Dolor provident tempora nobis quaerat
                    consequatur sequi alias illum veritatis.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
Note: I have not made my code responsive so please view on full page.
```

Comment: I don't see any line: [See This](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/zYooZpP?editors=1100)

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal Sorry I did a mistake on the code.  I have edited my code again. Now you should be able to see it.